# Tentando upload de JPG através de Javascript e Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload, jpg

Criei o seguinte formulário abaixo no site de um cliente, pra que se possa fazer a troca da foto de um usuário:

```
<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="blocoCampo">
        <span> Escolher nova foto (dimensões: 50px x 50px; formato: JPG) </span>
        <input type="file" id="imgupload" name="imgupload">
    </div>
    <div class="confirmarTrocaSenha">
        <input type="button" value="" id="btn_troca_foto">
    </div>
</form>
```

Em seguida, eu criei na função abaixo (javascript) pra ele conferir a extensão e as medições em Pixels do arquivo. Ele deve ser sempre 50x50 e JPG:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#imgupload").change(function (e) { // Aqui verifica as dimensões e a extensão do arquivo
    var foto = $('#imgupload').val();
    var extensao = foto.substr(foto.length - 3);
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            if(this.width !== 50){
                alert('Dimensões não permitidas!');
                $("#imgupload").val('');
            }
            else if(this. height !== 50){
                alert('Dimensões não permitidas!');
                $("#imgupload").val('');
            }
            else if(extensao != 'jpg'){
                alert('Extensão não permitida!');
                $("#imgupload").val('');
            }
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

E abaixo é a função que deve hospedar a foto, depois que a mesma for carregada:

```
$('#btn_troca_foto').click(function(){
    var imgupload = $('#imgupload').val();
    if(imgupload == ''){
        alert("Nenhuma foto selecionada!");
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: "trocarfoto",
            type: "POST",
            data: { imgupload: imgupload },
            success:function(a){
                alert(a);
                $('.contentLightbox, .bgLightbox').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

E o link da função **trocarfoto** está em PHP abaixo:

```
public static function trocaFoto() {
    @mkdir('upload/wt_usuario', 0777);
    $target = "upload/wt_usuario/" . $_SESSION['usuario']['id'] . ".jpg";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgupload']['tmp_name'], $target);
    echo "Foto de perfil alterada";
}
```

Tudo funcionando, menos a parte da função *move_uploaded_file*, que deveria pegar o arquivo que está no input *imgupload* e transferir pro diretório no servidor do meu site.

O que será que tem de errado ou que pode estar faltando? Sei que procurando na internet tem várias formas de fazer, mas acredito que esteja faltando apenas algum detalhes no meu código.

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer um upload via ajax você necessita de enviar os dados ligados ao formulário para iço necessita de esta parte de código.

Exemplo:

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        // o teu ficheiro PHP que vai guardar os dados no servidor
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        // dados do formulário
        data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
        // Diz ao Jquery que não processe os dados ou se preocupe com os dados que são enviados.
        // Tens de obrigatoriamente indicar estes para que os ficheiros não sejam corrompidos!
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                // Para veres o progresso do upload adiciona isto
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        $('progress').attr({
                            value: e.loaded,
                            max: e.total,
                        });
                    }
                } , false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
         success: function(data)
        {
         alert(data);//Nota que se não indicares qual o tipo de dados que esperas receber de volta, pode dar problemas. 
        }
});
```

upload.php:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
$name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo $name;
```

Se tiver alguma dúvida é só pedir ajuda, que eu tentarei ajudar.

Comment: Consegui a resposta que eu queria em outro fórum e funcionou. Obrigado mesmo assim. ;)